# How to check whether a ChromeCast device is available in the wifi network?

Tags: android, chromecast

I want to check for the availability of Chromecast device in the local network. Do we have a method in Chromecast APIs?

I want to hide the ActionBar if there is no Chromecast device available. I checked whether MediaRouter instance getting null when device is not available but that didn't work out.

Really appreciate if someone can give me a heads up.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a cast discovery and register to receive callbacks when a route is found or lost and keep track of that (probably in your Application instance if you need this info in multiple activities). Since cast devices  can join or leave a network at any time, you have to set up a dynamic mechanism like that. At any moment you can then ask the `MediaRouter` instance about the known discovered routes, if needed (remember that the book keeping of the route count should be done by you): `MediaRouter.getRoutes()`. A second approach that is not recommended is using mDNS discovery.